# How to make a "pop-up"-info box and a transparent gray over page?

Tags: javascript

I am making a page and I want to achieve something similar to this when clicking a button:

from this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPAQ6.jpg

to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hilZ5.jpg

Like a transparent gray coming up over teh page with a information box. How is that done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fount it!http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1256

Answer (score 0):

Just a FYI, that is called a modal.

Bootstrap and jQueryUI make it easy to accomplish.

[jQuery UI modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

[Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)